# Placing a preprocessor directive inside a string literal?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to use `#define` to define a string literal (a filepath in this case), but I cannot get the path FROM another #define'd element. In short, I'd like something like this:

```
#define X /var/stuff
#define Y "X/stuff.txt"
```

To give me `Y` as `"/var/stuff/stuff.txt"`.  Is this even possible to do?  Thanks beforehand.

EDIT: Alternatively, would something like this concat the two literals into one?

```
#define X "/var/stuff"
#define Y X"/stuff.txt"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the way you have it, no -- macro replacement does not happen inside string literals.

You can, however, paste together a string from pieces:

```
#define str(x) #x
#define expand(x) str(x)

#define X /var/stuff
#define Y expand(X) "/stuff.txt"
```

Quick demo code for this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << Y;
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to make a string literal out of two macros then?

Comment: @SuperTron yes, but its ugly and involves some multi level preprocessor voodoo

Comment: I believe OPs edits would actually work as-is

Comment: Yes, they sure do :)  Thanks!

Comment: Yes -- if you don't mind defining everything as a string literal up-front, then you can just put them next to each other, and the compiler will concatenate them together for you.